# The Apk file exported from Android Studio is too large

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have never used Android Studio before. The size of a simple "Hello world" app generated by default is almost 800k, while it is less than 100k in eclipse. I find that there are too many pictures in the drawable files, they seem come from `res/all` under the `build` folder, they still exist even if I delete the folder `res` manually.

My question is how to shrink the apk size in this situation?

Comment: How do you export api from android studio? Do you use gradle for build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is due to the appcompat library which is compiled in by default to New Project Wizard-generated projects in Android Studio if you target an API level lower than 14. When I ran a test, the size increase was 642k for a debug APK, and 411k for a release APK (with Proguard enabled -- that will strip out unused code but not unused resources).

There's not a lot you can really do about this, short of removing the appcompat library if you're not using any of its features (though you should probably be using its features).

Comment: Thanks! I had `appcompat` automatically attached although I didn't need it. Just remove whatever useless dependency there is (via editing module's gradle file or via Project Settings > Dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Android Studio yet (my understanding is that it's still beta), but, I know that with other IDEs, the size of the resulting executable will change based on if it's a Debug or Release version.  Eclipse lets you specify one or the other.  Does Android Studio do the same?

Comment: Have some courage when down voting by specifying a reason.  Especially on an old post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "shrinkResources" in (build.gradle app)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size